# 24-hours time with 12-hour notation

Tags: email, date-time, timestamp

I've received an paper e-mail copy with header saying, that the e-mail was sent **15:10 PM**. So I am wondering, if the mail is fake one, or is it possible due to some setting changes?

My questions:

1. Is it possible to have such a time setting in any mail client? (MS Outloook, web-based etc.)
2. Is it even possible to program such time type in any programming language?

EDIT: The header is similiar like this [one](http://www.outlookprinter.com/images/usual_printout.png), just the time is as stated above 15:10 PM.

Comment: More information would be needed. A screenshot would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

To achieve such a thing, you just need to customize date format in **Regional Settings** control panel. Most applications then use the setting, including the Outlook.

So the explanation can be that person who printed the e-mail had set unusual time format on their PC.

See the following screenshot with similar example and its impact on clock in notification area:

[image]

*Apologies to readers, currently I'm on machine with Czech Windows 7. OTOH, the OP seems to be from Czech rep., so he can read it in his mother tongue.* :)