# converting time in excel and/or adding +12 hours

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, time, date-time, date

I have this time in excel `2019-08-04T06:48:45.000Z`
[image]

It is in GMT time, **how do I convert it to +12 hours?**
So what I want is 2019-08-04T18:48:45.000Z.

That's an easier one(just have to change the hour) but I want to change the date too as will be required.
E.G This: 
2019-08-04T22:35:15.000Z 
To This: 
2019-08-05T10:35:15.000Z

So far I can convert the hh:mm:ss.sss part of the string `2019-08-04T06:48:45.000Z` to decimal value `0.28`
 and then reformat that and it gives me 6:48:45 a.m. [image]

I still have to add 12 hours to this, I am thinking I will convert 12 hours to decimal and then add this. 
**But how would I go about adding to the date/day part of the string?**

possible related questions which I will look into: 
 
[Converting time from text to hours and minutes in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1214426/converting-time-from-text-to-hours-and-minutes-in-excel) 
 
[24-hours time with 12-hour notation](https://superuser.com/questions/952451/24-hours-time-with-12-hour-notation) 
 
[Converting time string text to hours and minutes in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1389128/converting-time-string-text-to-hours-and-minutes-in-excel)

[dropbox file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwj5rt9z968x56a/grafana_data_export%287%29.xlsx?dl=0) columns N:AJ are of Interest

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `Z` part in the date/time string means `Zulu time`, aka GMT. If you convert it to another time zone, it is no longer `Z` but `GMT + 12`

Comment: tks but how do I do the conversion you speak of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula that:

---

1. Creates a true date/time: `REPLACE(LEFT(A1,23),11,1," ")`
2. Adds 12 hours: `+TIME(12,0,0)`
3. Then formats it back to the original format `"yyyy-mm-dd\Thh:mm:ss.000\Z"`:

---

```
=TEXT(REPLACE(LEFT(A1,23),11,1," ")+TIME(12,0,0),"yyyy-mm-dd\Thh:mm:ss.000\Z")
```

[image]